# MySQL joins involving aggregate data

Tags: mysql

What I require is a SQL query which can report on data from aggregate and singular tables. The current database I have is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faults_days` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `day_date` date NOT NULL,
    `actioned_calls_out` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `actioned_calls_in` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `actioned_tickets` int(11) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faults_departments` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faults_employees` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(127) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faults_qos` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `qos_date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `score` double NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `faults_teams` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `department_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
)
```

A row in `Day` tracks a single employee's performance for a single day (number of calls taken, number of tickets actioned). A Qos is a measure of an employee's quality on a day (there can be more than one Qos per day - what I need to obtain is the average score). Also, a Qos can be performed on a day where the employee has no performance entry in the database, and this will still need to be shown on the report.

The required end result is 4 reports, which show the employee performance grouped by different columns. A breakdown of a single employee's performance per day, an employee's total performance over a period of time, a team's performance over a period of time, and a whole department's performance over a period of time.

My problem, is that my current queries are a little convoluted, and require two separate queries for the `Day` data, and the `Qos` data. My PHP application then combines the data before outputting the report. *What I would like, is a single query which returns both total performance, and average quality scores.*

The current queries I have to show employee performances are:

```
SELECT  
    `Employee`.`name` ,  
    `Team`.`name` , 
    `Department`.`name` , 
    SUM(  `Day`.`actioned_calls_in` ) + SUM(  `Day`.`actioned_calls_out` ) , 
    SUM(  `Day`.`actioned_tickets` ) 
FROM  
    `faults_days` AS  `Day` 
JOIN  
    `faults_employees` AS  `Employee` ON  `Day`.`employee_id` =  `Employee`.`id` 
JOIN  
    `faults_teams` AS  `Team` ON  `Employee`.`team_id` =  `Team`.`id` 
JOIN  
    `faults_departments` AS  `Department` ON  `Team`.`department_id` =  `Department`.`id` 
WHERE  
    `Day`.`day_date` >=  '2011-06-01'
    AND  `Day`.`day_date` <=  '2011-06-07'
GROUP BY  `Employee`.`id` 
WITH ROLLUP
```

and

```
SELECT  
    `Employee`.`name` ,  
    `Team`.`name` ,  
    `Department`.`name` , 
    COUNT(  `Qos`.`score` ) , 
    AVG(  `Qos`.`score` ) 
FROM  
    `faults_qos` AS  `Qos` 
JOIN  
    `faults_employees` AS  `Employee` ON  `Qos`.`employee_id` =  `Employee`.`id` 
JOIN  
    `faults_teams` AS  `Team` ON  `Employee`.`team_id` =  `Team`.`id` 
JOIN  
    `faults_departments` AS  `Department` ON  `Team`.`department_id` =  `Department`.`id` 
WHERE  
    `Qos`.`qos_date` >=  '2011-06-01'
    AND  `Qos`.`qos_date` <=  '2011-06-07'
GROUP BY  `Employee`.`id` 
WITH ROLLUP
```

I have also tried simply joining the Qos table, but because it returns multiple rows it messes up the `SUM()` totals, and also has problems due to the missing `FULL OUTER JOIN` functionality.

**EDIT:**
I've made some *small* progress with this. It looks like using subqueries is the way to go,  but everything I'm doing is pure guesswork. Here's what I've got so far, its only showing a row if there's an entry in both the `Day` and `Qos` tables, which is not what I want, and I've no idea how to expand it to include the various groupings described above.

```
SELECT  
    `Employee`.`name` ,  
    `Team`.`name` , 
    `Department`.`name`,
    `Day`.`Calls`,
    `Day`.`Tickets`,
    `Qos`.`NumQos`,
    `Qos`.`Score`
FROM `faults_employees` AS  `Employee` 
JOIN  
    `faults_teams` AS  `Team` ON  `Employee`.`team_id` =  `Team`.`id` 
JOIN  
    `faults_departments` AS  `Department` ON  `Team`.`department_id` =  `Department`.`id` 
JOIN
    (SELECT
        `Day`.`employee_id` AS `eid`,
        SUM(`Day`.`actioned_calls_in`) + SUM(`Day`.`actioned_calls_out`) AS `Calls`, 
        SUM(`Day`.`actioned_tickets`) AS `Tickets`
    FROM `faults_days` AS `Day`
    WHERE
        `Day`.`day_date` = '2011-03-02'
    GROUP BY `Day`.`employee_id`
    ) AS `Day`
    ON `Day`.`eid` = `Employee`.`id`
JOIN
    (SELECT
        `Qos`.`employee_id` AS qid,
        COUNT(`Qos`.`id`) AS `NumQos`,
        AVG(`Qos`.`score`) AS `Score`
    FROM `faults_qos` AS `Qos`
    WHERE
        `Qos`.`qos_date` = '2011-03-02'
    GROUP BY `Qos`.`employee_id`
    ) AS `Qos`
    ON `Qos`.`qid` = `Employee`.`id`
GROUP BY `Employee`.`id`
```

Comment: This is not a 'please do my job for me' website. What do you have so far? And post your database schema.

Comment: too verbous. Post the problem/error you have

Comment: Appreciate the comments. I've now edited the question to include what I've already got.

Comment: Good question. That's left in there from an earlier attempt at solving this myself using UNION ALL. I'll edit it out

Comment: @Jack, if the `left join`s aren't necessary, then if you think of `faults_employees` as your main table and join subqueries for `faults_qos` and `faults_days` it should work for you... Let me know if you need more than that and I'll try to flesh out a real answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll be honest, this isn't something I had considered before. I thought joining with subqueries would be something I required, however I haven't been able to get this quite right. I'll give it a go a bit later on.

Comment: I've had a quick look, but have a couple of questions that I can't quite figure out. Doing this, will this return data from `faults_days` even if there is nothing from `faults_qos`, will the reverse also happen? This is the required behaviour. Once again, I'll look into this in more detail later today, but your input is definitely appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a little more complicated than I had originally thought. I've made an attempt at solving this myself using subqueries, but I'm failing miserably... I've edited the question with my new attempt. Any further direction would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do want the `left join`s on the `fault_qos` and `fault_days` subqueries. That's what will give you a result even if there isn't a corresponding row in one or both. A `left join` says that the value is necessary in the table(s) to the left of the join that are involved in the join but not the one on the right. I haven't tested this, and it's late, so I might not be thinking clearly, but if you change your query to this it should work:

```
SELECT  
    `Employee`.`name` ,  
    `Team`.`name` , 
    `Department`.`name`,
    `Day`.`Calls`,
    `Day`.`Tickets`,
    `Qos`.`NumQos`,
    `Qos`.`Score`
FROM `faults_employees` AS  `Employee` 
JOIN  
    `faults_teams` AS  `Team` ON  `Employee`.`team_id` =  `Team`.`id` 
JOIN  
    `faults_departments` AS  `Department` ON  `Team`.`department_id` =  `Department`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        `Day`.`employee_id` AS `eid`,
        SUM(`Day`.`actioned_calls_in`) + SUM(`Day`.`actioned_calls_out`) AS `Calls`, 
        SUM(`Day`.`actioned_tickets`) AS `Tickets`
    FROM `faults_days` AS `Day`
    WHERE
        `Day`.`day_date` = '2011-03-02'
    GROUP BY `Day`.`employee_id`
    ) AS `Day`
    ON `Day`.`eid` = `Employee`.`id`
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        `Qos`.`employee_id` AS qid,
        COUNT(`Qos`.`id`) AS `NumQos`,
        AVG(`Qos`.`score`) AS `Score`
    FROM `faults_qos` AS `Qos`
    WHERE
        `Qos`.`qos_date` = '2011-03-02'
    GROUP BY `Qos`.`employee_id`
    ) AS `Qos`
    ON `Qos`.`qid` = `Employee`.`id`
GROUP BY `Employee`.`id`
```

Comment: I've had to include the other joins (`Team` and `Department`) in both the subqueries in order to fulfil the other grouping requirements, but otherwise this is absolutely perfect! Thanks a lot